# Can single-mode fiber collect incoherent light?

Tags: optics

I am now studying the rotational Doppler effect of partially coherent light, and I theoretically calculate that the cross-spectral density of completely incoherent light when coupled into a fiber is zero, but my instructor doesn't think so.

Comment: I also think it shouldn't be zero: if you think about your completely incoherent light, there is still *some* probability of being in the correct mode for the fiber to collect, so a fraction should be collected

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience, I will check again。